# How to change what the Digital Crown initially scrolls in a SwiftUI view?

Tags: swift, swiftui, watchos

I have a SwiftUI view in an Apple Watch app. The very basic structure is this:

```
List {
Slider()
ListRow()
...
}
```

When navigating to the view, the Digital Crown controls the slider instead of scrolling the whole list. Upon touching the screen to scroll, the crown's focus changes to the list and it is then scrollable.

The desired behaviour is for the crown to initially scroll the List, then control the slider upon touch interaction with it.

How can I change what the crown first 'attaches' itself to?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I have similar problem. Did you find solution to this?